# How to disable "Permission denied" output when using find

Tags: bash, find

I'm running a script to find some file on a server:

```
find / -group usergroup -user jondoe -size 33c
```

Now my problem is, what is the most convenient way to only display the real results? In my output, there are a lot of files where find ran into a permission denied, but this is not really helpful. I suppose there is some kind of grep wizardry necessary to get only the results not producing a permission denied?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Hint: two outputs: Stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find / -group usergroup -user jondoe -size 33c 2> /dev/null
```

2 is the stderr stream, the stream where errors should be put from a programm in case of an error.
With `> /dev/null` you redirect that output to `/dev/null` so you only get the output pasted to stdout from find, the stream where all output from a programm should go which are not error.

Comment: Such a wise solution +1